refresh scaffold screen on browser back button for web app with GoRouter?
I recently added web as a platform on my mobile flutter app. Updated all my navigation code to use GoRouter package.
We cannot use await on context.go and I don't want to use context.push as the url is not deep linkable.
When I press back button on browser or use context.pop, I want my previous screen to reload fresh just like any webpage would load. but I am not able to figure this out.
Please advice. Thanks in advance.
P.S I am not using any state management package rn. Do I have to implement a package like Riverpod to achieve this?

Normally the context.pop will persist the previous state in the navigation tree. If you just want to start over a new fresh page, please consider using context.go('previous_page') instead of context.pop
Please check this document out for more details: https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-navigation-gorouter-go-vs-push/

I tried this. but the init method is still not called. where I have put there refresh logic
